# "Strict with punctuality" vs. "Strict about punctuality"

Tags: meaning, prepositions, difference

How would the meaning change, if we changed the prepositions in the following sentences? The following were extracted from [Longman Dictionary Online](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/strict).

> This company is very strict **about** punctuality. ( with)
>
> The Trumps are very strict **with** their children. (about)

Comment: "Strict *with* your children" relates to the rules you set for your children to follow. "Strict *about* your children" isn't a common expression, but I would interpret it as being about rules you have about how other people interact with your children. So if the Trumps were strict *about* their children perhaps that might mean for example that they try to keep the kids' pictures from appearing in the newspaper.

Comment: This isn't really a matter of grammar. Idiomatically, [*strict **about** punctuality*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=strict+with+punctuality%2Cstrict+about+punctuality%2Cstrict+on+punctuality&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cstrict%20about%20punctuality%3B%2Cc0) is the most common form, but that doesn't make alternatives *wrong*. Note that [*strict **on** punctuality*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22strict+on+punctuality%22) is in fact much more common than ***with***, but they're both "acceptable".

Answer (score 1):

A common meaning of *X with Y* is being used to express "instrumentality".  In this case, it's mostly equivalent to using the words "whenever X use(s)/used Y".

> X is strict with punctuality = X is strict whenever X uses punctuality.

*Punctuality* is not something that is often "used" (like a tool or thing needed to complete an activity) so this would likely sound strange, but a possible valid meaning (and implication if you say this) would be if a manager or someone is known to "use" punctuality to find people to fire or get in trouble.

*X about Y* is more general than *with* and doesn't just mean "when X uses Y":

> X is strict about punctuality = X is strict with anything X does that has to do with punctuality.

So, if you say something like "My manager is strict about punctuality" - you are saying that anything he/she does as a manager that also would deal with punctuality - he/she would be strict in whatever actions he/she would be doing.  All the normal things a manager does in regard to punctuality - whatever they are, he/she is strict while doing those things.

Comment: x about is on the subject of.

Answer (score 0):

Longman's DCE has "strict about sth" and "strict with sb".   [Link](http://Your%20first%20sentence%20about%20the%20nature%20of%20a%20gerund%20is%20of%20very%20low%20qulity,%20or%20rather%20it%20is%20simply%20wrong.%20The%20gerund%20is%20a%20verbform%20with%20the%20ending%20-ing,%20just%20as%20the%20present%20participle,%20and%20it%20has%20the%20nature%20of%20a%20verb%20and%20a%20noun.%20The%20gerund%20has%20four%20forms,%20two%20active%20and%20two%20passive%20forms:%20%20doing,%20having%20%20done,%20%20being%20printed,%20having%20been%20printed.%20The%20gerund%20has%20two%20difficulties,%20one%20being%20its%20double%20nature%20of%20having%20verbal%20and%20noun%20character,%20the%20second%20difficulty%20being%20that%20gerund%20and%20present%20participle%20have%20the%20same%20form.)
OALD does not mention this construction.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Longman DCE says strict about punctuality and strict with children.http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/strict. Sorry, the link above doesn't seem to work.